# Zombie Game - Collision Detection issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, collision-detection

http://designedbychristian.com/designedbychristian/u-vs-them/

That is what I am working on. You can use your arrow keys to move and space bar to shoot.
And I am testing in Chrome.

I am trying to do collision detection with the bullet hitting the zombies(red divs)

```
setInterval(function(){
   var z = $(".zombie");
   var zoff = z.offset();
   var zleft = zoff.left;

   var b = $("#bullet");
   var boff = b.offset();
   var bleft = boff.left;
      if (localStorage.getItem('facing') == "right") {
          if (bleft >= zleft) {
              $("#zombie").remove()
              $("#bullet").remove()
            }  
            }else if (localStorage.getItem('facing') == "left") {
                if (bleft <= zleft) {
                $("#zombie").remove()
                $("#bullet").remove()
            }
      }

      },1);
```

My problem is that the bullet is taking out the zombies in the order of the thier spawning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the selector using `#` will just take the first element with that ID. What you need to do is use a selector that finds all the zombies and checks if each one has been hit, then remove that one, instead of just checking the first one.

Use `var z = $(".zombie");` to select all elements with the class `zombie` (as opposed to those with that ID) then look at this to figure out the rest: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

If you're still having problems I can try to post more code for you, but give it a go first ;) The game's looking pretty cool so far.

**Edit**: Ok, so looked at your updated code and what's going wrong is that you're using `each` to select and remove all of the zombies after trying to compare the whole list with the bullet.
This code will remove all of the zombies no matter what:

```
$('.zombie').each(function () {
    $(this).remove()
})
```

What you really need to be doing is select all of the zombies, *then* use `each` to loop through the list of zombies and compare each one to the bullet once, and only delete it if there is a collision. Something like this should work as the contents of your `setInterval`, though you may need to tweak it a little:

```
var b = $("#bullet");
var boff = b.offset();
var bleft = boff.left;
$('.zombie').each(function () {
    var z = $(this);
    var zoff = z.offset();
    var zleft = zoff.left;

    if (localStorage.getItem('facing') == "right") {
        if (bleft >= zleft) {
            z.remove()
            b.remove()
            score++
        }
    } else if (localStorage.getItem('facing') == "left") {
        if (bleft <= zleft) {
            z.remove()
            b.remove()
            score++
        }
    }
}
```

Also, to optimise this, you might want to make a check at the beginning of the loop to see if the bullet has already hit a zombie - if so, the loop won't need to continue and run the rest of the code. I'll leave this up to you though.

Comment: Also, for proper semantics, he should not be using the same id for every div (nor referencing them by id). He already assigns them class "zombie" so he should use `$(".zombie")`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I intended to use the class selector, but copied his code and then forgot to change the `#`!

Comment: No problem. Be sure to add a brief note about why you changed the `#` to a `.` in your solution though.

Comment: Good idea... and done, hope that'll do - too tired for any more SO tonight.

Comment: Thank you! I changed it from # to .
As far as using the each() I have tried to but have failed. I never used it before but I got it to delete the nearest one but it removes them all the zombies due to them having the same class even though i used $(this).remove()

I updated the site. Use inspect element to see changes

Comment: If you give me a while I'll try to have a look later on - got a busy day today but I'll check it out when I get a chance.

Comment: Hey buddy, I took a look at your new code and edited my answer to reflect it. Hope it fixes it for you! If not, it may be an idea to ask a new question as it's starting to be about a different problem now. Happy to help some more if needed though.